# Formatting ERB Templates automatically in textmate

Tags: ruby-on-rails, textmate, erb, textmatebundles

When writing ERB templates in Ruby on Rails using Textmate formatting by hand pretty much sucks.

Do anyone know of a textmate bundle that handles formatting of ERB templates/views?  My googling has found nothing. Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean with formatting by hand? I think the built-in Textmate Bundle for Rails is great.

Comment: Auto-formatting the views.     When your writing straight HTML in Textmate, you can use the HTML bundle Tidy command to "cleanup" a HTML file.    I'm looking for an ERB equivalent to the HTML Tidy command.

Comment: This is SOO annoying.  Would love to find a good solution to this.

Answer (score 2):

I think the best solution is to use the HTML (Rails) bundle. 
And when you want to tidy something, you'll need to go up to the Bundles menu > HTML > Tidy.

That coupled with Indent Selection (<kbd>⌘</kbd>-<kbd>⌥</kbd>-<kbd>[</kbd>) , handles most of my reformatting needs.

NOTE: unfortunately, when in the HTML (Rails) bundle, the normal tidy shortcut <kbd>⌃</kbd>-<kbd>⇧</kbd>-<kbd>H</kbd> gets overridden and instead launches the "Create a partial from the selected text" when in a *.html.erb file. I'm sure there's a way to change this but it hasn't been a big enough deal for me to investigate.

Comment: ⌥⌘[ gets you almost there but for some reason doesn't indent blocks in ERB correctly.  Really wish there was a better solution for this.

Comment: HTML > Tidy via the menu would attempt to make your partial HTML snippet a full HTML document with DOCTYPE etc...